# confusing css selector syntax ".tablediv h3 {}"

Tags: css-selectors

I'm learning a web design course on Coursera and this snippet of code confuses me:

```
.tablediv h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I understand simple selector `h3 {}` or class selector `.tablediv {}` but what's the syntax of `.tablediv h3` here? Thanks~

Comment: It (the space) is a descendant selector:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Comment: That makes sense! Thx Alex!